# Native Swift/Obj-C app for tvOS - But how to display web page in TVML?

Tags: tvos, apple-tv, tvml

I'll admit I am being a little lazy, but I'm sure a lot of devs will have this same question going forward.

So I use `openUrl` for a lot of our legal stuff (TOS, Privacy) in our SettingsVC on iOS. I'm creating a new tvOS app in Swift, and have to figure out how to show this text content from the web.

Some options:

1. Hardcode the text (not an option since we want to be able to update by pushing to a web server)
2. Create a separate API endpoint for the text (possible, but would rather not)
3. Somehow get the text from our web links and display in an appropriate view.

I want to do 3, but am not sure how as I'm new to tvOS. Is there some kind of TVML view that I can implement like a webview to load the url and display the returned HTML?

Comment: How did you solve this?

Answer (score 2):

tvOS does not contain WebKit. You cannot display HMTL. You have to display the text without urls inside a TVML template.

Answer (score 0):

You can implement your own TVML-item with the `TVMLKit`. There are some custom projects that using private API to allow you to use `UIWebView` in the tvOS (for example https://github.com/steventroughtonsmith/tvOSBrowser) with the Objective-C language. So, you can wrap the browser in a TVML-item and use is it in a TVML-files.